# Methods after performSegueWithIdentifier guaranteed to execute?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uikit

Simple testing shows methods after performSegueWithIdentifier can execute, but is it safe to make this assumption?

The Apple documentation says nothing on this topic.

For instance, the `print` statement in the code block below executed in tests. But let's say you want to log something to an online analytics service, or do something more complex than a print statement? Can you assume statements after performSegueWithIdentifier are guaranteed to execute, or should you put the those lines of code before performSegueWithIdentifier?

```
    performSegueWithIdentifier(TestSegue, sender: self)
    print("YO YO YO")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
performSegueWithIdentifier(TestSegue, sender: self)
```

is actually the last thing that gets called in the function you are in. If the other calls made in the function don't end, it will never transition you until everything executes. For example, say you have the following code:

```
@IBAction func button1Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {


    performSegueWithIdentifier("toIMG", sender: nil)

    let temp = imageViewController()
    temp.printingStuff()
}
```

and the imageViewController looks like this:

```
class imageViewController: UIViewController {

[....]

func printingStuff(){
    while true{
    print("I love pizza")

    }

}
```

it will actually keep printing and never transition you into the next view.